# Is there a way to force-invoke of parent overriden method?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Basic idea looks like

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
  void some_public() {};
private:
    class CallMe
    {
        friend class Base;
    };
protected:

    virtual CallMe doSomething()
    {
        return {}
    }
};
```

so private class trick will force any child class to call `Base` method if override it;

```
class MidChild: public Base
{
protected:
    virtual CallMe doSomething() override
    {
        //do some middle specific code

        return Base::doSomething()
    }
}
```

so `Base::doSomething()` must be force invoked

```
class LastChild: public MidChild
{
protected:
    virtual CallMe doSomething() override final
    {
        //do some last child specific code
        // invoke base method because its forced to
        return Base::doSomething()
    }
}
```

So the main trouble that we should invoke `MidChild::doSomething()` instead of `Base::doSomething`; because we need `MidChild` actions too. Is there a way to force that kind of invocation chain i.e. call previous inheritance level parent's method instead of base one?

Comment: `return MidChild::doSomething();`?

Comment: you can do both, but trouble is to force to invoke exactly `MidChild::doSomething` but not `BaseScene::doSomething`

Comment: @Sugar: Your comment is quite unclear. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Use a coding convention? Add a `parent` typedef to each class and always call base class functions as `parent::doSomething()`. The language doesn't help you with this.

Comment: @Jaa-c Usage private class/struct to return from your function with only base class as its friend will force you to call base class function because that kind of friendship is not inherited by derived classes and it will make compile-time error if you forgot to invoke